# When i set these images position to fixed, they pile on top of each other

Tags: html, css

The css below is what I've applied to the Facebook, twitter, and Google plus links, I've added to a website I'm making, I want to make it so that when i scroll down on the website the Facebook, twitter, and Google plus icons stay in the top, right hand corner of the screen.
I added `position: fixed;` to it and they stay in that corner when i scroll; however, they pile on top of each other, this should come easy to me, but my brains blank:

```
.facebook {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
background: transparent url('Styling-Images/fb.png') center top no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
margin-right:5px;
position: fixed;
```

}

```
.facebook:hover {
    background-image: url('Styling-Images/bgcolor.png');
```

}

```
.twitter {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
background: transparent url('Styling-Images/tw.png') center top no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
margin-right:5px;
position: fixed;
```

}

```
.twitter:hover {
    background-image: url('Styling-Images/bgcolor.png');
```

}

```
.gp {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
background: transparent url('Styling-Images/gp.png') center top no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
margin-right:5px;
position: fixed;
```

}

```
.gp:hover {
   background-image: url('Styling-Images/bgcolor.png');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first create an div element with fixed position then put all images in that.

Don't use fix position for images because it will overlap each image

Comment: Ok thanks that worked, but I had them right aligned and now they are fixed to the left side, ive tried putting text-align: right; and float: right;, and neither work

Comment: @user2758912: If you worked it out, you should provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pGdA8/2/). Giving

```
 margin-right:5px;
```

for all the items is causing the problem.

```
        .facebook {
           width: 40px;
           height: 40px;
           display: inline-block;
           background: transparent url('http://ottopilotmedia.com/wp- content/uploads/2012/07/facebook-icon.jpg') center top no-repeat;
           background-size: contain;
           float:left;
        }
```